# How to avoid rerendering of of my other components with the help of useCallback when my one component's state is updated

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have two components 1. counter component which has a button  called **ADD** to increase the count and 2. Profile component which also has a button called **ADD USER**, profile component does nothing except it console logs a hello message upon clicking the add user button, also it console logs *"profile was rendered"* each time it is being rendered/rerendered.
I'm using context api inside ContextHook.js file with useState to manage the state.Inside ConextHook.js , I have two function wrapped in  **useCallback()** with empty array []  as dependency to avoid unnecessary rerendering my components. But when I click on ADD inside Counter component to update the counter my Profile component also gets rerendered. It seems useCallback has no effect.

here is my Pofile.js component

```
import React from 'react'
import { useAddUser } from './ContexHook'

function Profile() {
  console.log('profile was rendered');
  const addUser = useAddUser();

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Profile</p>
      <button onClick={addUser}>ADD USER</button>
    </div >

  )
}

export default Profile
```

Counter.js component

```
import React from 'react'
import { useAdd, useAddCount } from './ContexHook'

function Counter() {
  const add = useAdd();
  const count = useAddCount();
  return (

    <div>
      <p>Counter : {count}</p>
      <button onClick={add}>ADD</button></div>


  )
}

export default Counter
```

ContextHook.js

```
import { createContext, useCallback, useContext, useState } from "react";

export const CartContext = createContext();

const useStore = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  return (
    {
      count,
      addUser: useCallback(() => console.log('hello'), []),
      add: useCallback(() => setCount(preCount => preCount + 1), [])
    }
  )
}

function CartProvider({ children }) {
  return (
    <CartContext.Provider value={useStore()}>
      {children}
    </CartContext.Provider>
  )
}

export const useAdd = () => useContext(CartContext).add
export const useAddUser = () => useContext(CartContext).addUser
export const useAddUserCount = () => useContext(CartContext).user
export const useAddCount = () => useContext(CartContext).count

export default CartProvider;
```

I wanted my Counter component to be update only when I tap on ADD button , but my Profile component  gets rendered unnecessarily.I want to avoid this.